# How to use INSERT INTO and UPDATE together in one mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have to use INSERT INTO command to pick up data from a database then on the same table I want to use update command(which depends on the values inserted through Insert into command).
I want to use one single query for both insert into and update command?

You can refer to my commands

```
INSERT INTO `cr_score_table`(`User_Id`,`CR_Id`, `Question_attempted`, `Score`) 
SELECT wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic_ref.user_id,wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic.statistic_ref_id, SUM(wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic.solved_count), SUM(wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic.correct_count)
FROM wordpress.wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic_ref
LEFT JOIN wordpress.wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic
ON wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic_ref.statistic_ref_id = wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic.statistic_ref_id
Group By statistic_ref_id
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cr_score_table.CR_Id=cr_score_table.CR_Id
```

AND

```
UPDATE cr_score_table AS X JOIN (
SELECT
  s1.CR_Id, COUNT(s2.CR_Id)/ (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cr_score_table) * 100 AS percentile
FROM
  cr_score_table s1 JOIN cr_score_table s2 on (s2.score <= s1.score)
GROUP BY s1.Cr_Id
ORDER BY s1.Cr_Id) AS Z 
ON (X.Cr_Id = Z.Cr_Id) 
SET X.Score_Percentile = Z.percentile, `Name`= (Select Name
                                     From user_table
                                     WHERE user_table.User_Id = X.User_Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 separate queries and use the mysql

```
LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

on your UPDATE query

Comment: I didn't got you....I want to write both functions in one query..Can you write one query for me using queries I have written